# Error dissolving shapefile with ogr and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, shapefile, ogr

I'm trying to dissolve a shapefile based on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85028/dissolve-aggregate-polygons-with-ogr2ogr-or-gpc) and [that instruction](http://darrencope.com/2015/01/23/dissolve-shapefiles-using-ogr/). However, when I run my line of code:

```
ogr2ogr "c:/working/testing/dissolve.shp" "c:/working/testing/test.shp" -f"ESRI Shapefile" -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM 'test'"
```

I get the following Error:

```
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_step(SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM 'temp_2'): SQL logic error or missing database
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: The "Dissolve" algorithm of QGIS works perfectly fine (not the one which uses ogr2ogr, but their own). Is there any magic I don't understand?

Comment: You are missing the actual error message. Does `ogr2ogr` really keep it secret?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I sorted it out by myself. The reason for the failure was that within the shapefile, some features had been marked as deleted, as per this error message when reading single features:

```
ERROR 1: Attempt to read shape with feature id (0), but it is marked deleted.
```

I was now able to work around this by copying the shapefile, which also repacks it and deletes all features that are marked as such. With this new copy, the initial line of code works perfectly fine.